# Create composite key - operating across rows in a dataset

Tags: version-10, dataset

I would like to be able to create a new dataset by extracting 2 columns to make a composite key, and also extracting other columns.  For example, suppose my dataset looked like:

[image]

I would like to create:

```
{<| New Key -> {2013, TYML143}, Earned Prem Est -> -19322.6|>,
 <| New Key -> {2013, TYML143}, Earned Prem Est -> -7323.55|>,
 <| New Key -> {2013, TYML529}, Earned Prem Est -> -2259.94|>,
 ...}
```

Comment: +1 but just a comment, `{2013, TYML143} -> data` is a composite `Key`, whereas the list is the `Value` here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have your data as a `Dataset`, for example, using m_goldberg's data:

```
ds= Dataset[data]
```

You can get a new `Dataset` as follows:

```
ds[All, <|"newKey" -> {#year, #id}, "qty" -> #qty|> &]
```

[image: New dataset]

Or if you want a list of Associations:

```
ds[All, <|"newKey" -> {#year, #id}, "qty" -> #qty|> &] //Normal
```

> ```
> {<|"newKey" -> {2012, "abc"}, "qty" -> 123|>,
>  <|"newKey" -> {2012, "def"}, "qty" -> 456|>,
>  <|"newKey" -> {2013, "abc"}, "qty" -> 321|>, 
>  <|"newKey" -> {2013, "ghi"}, "qty" -> 42|>, 
>  <|"newKey" -> {2014, "abc"}, "qty" -> 312|>}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

First I have to make some data, since no data in copyable form was given in the question.

```
keys = {"year", "id", "qty"};
vals = 
  {{2012, "abc", 123}, {2012, "def", 456}, {2013, "abc", 321}, 
   {2013, "ghi", 42}, {2014, "abc", 312}};
data = AssociationThread[keys, #] & /@ vals
```

> ```
> {<|"year" -> 2012, "id" -> "abc", "qty" -> 123|>, 
>  <|"year" -> 2012, "id" -> "def", "qty" -> 456|>, 
>  <|"year" -> 2013, "id" -> "abc", "qty" -> 321|>, 
>  <|"year" -> 2013, "id" -> "ghi", "qty" -> 42|>, 
>  <|"year" -> 2014, "id" -> "abc", "qty" -> 312|>}
> ```

Given the data, a composition of `MapThread`, `Join`, `Map`, `KeyDrop`, `KeyTake` and `Values` will do the job. Perhaps it can be expressed more succinctly, but I've been much good at code golf.

```
MapThread[
  Join, 
  {<|"newKey" -> #|> & /@ (KeyDrop[data, "qty"] // Values), KeyTake[data, "qty"]}]
```

> ```
> {<|"newKey" -> {2012, "abc"}, "qty" -> 123|>, 
>  <|"newKey" -> {2012, "def"}, "qty" -> 456|>, 
>  <|"newKey" -> {2013, "abc"}, "qty" -> 321|>,
>  <|"newKey" -> {2013, "ghi"}, "qty" -> 42|>, 
>  <|"newKey" -> {2014, "abc"}, "qty" -> 312|>}
> ```